# RecyclerView not responding to a click despite touch feedback

Tags: java, android

I have two cards in a row of a recyclerview, Here's the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:textColor="@color/md_teal_900"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_default_thumbnail"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="10"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/download_card"
        card_view:cardElevation = "10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/md_white_1000">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_download"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I press on either of the cards, there is a touch feedback, but no response.

Here's how I'm handling the click in my adapter.

```
    public XViewHolder(View itemView, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        this.adapter = adapter;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = this.getAdapterPosition();
        if(v.getId() == R.id.card) {
            mainView.startVideoFragment(JsonList.get(position).getURL());
        }else{
            DownloadStream downloadStream = new DownloadStream(
                    JsonList.get(position).getURL(), JsonList.get(position).getTitle());
        }
    }
```

The onClick method is not even called.

Comment: try it in your LinearLayout
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`
also try to remove it.. `clickable="true"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The onClick method is not even called.

That's not true. The method is called but you are not registering a `ClickListener` for  `R.id.card` so the first guard is always false. In your `else` branch you are instantiating `DownloadStream` but you are not doing nothing with it. If you want to explicitly handle click events for the different view, you have to explicitly register the `OnClickListener` for the specific child. E.g.

```
itemView.findViewById(R.id.card).setOnClickListener(this);
```

to get the `onClick` called when you click on `R.id.card`, and

```
 itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_card).setOnClickListener(this);
```

if you want to handle the click for `R.id.download_card`

Comment: I set breakpoints, and nothing inside of onClick was called. Not even `int position`. How do I register a clickListener for R.id.card?

Comment: are you sure that the breakpoints is executable ? Are you running your app in debug mode ?

Comment: to register the click listener on card you simply do `itemView.findViewById(R.id.card).setOnClickListener(true);`

Comment: What's the difference if I do `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`. That's how I did it. It was working before I added the second card, that is, download_card.

Comment: itemView and R.id.card are two different views.

Comment: How so? itemView is the view object which inflates the layout. Anyways, doing `itemView.findViewById(R.id.card).setOnClickListener(this);` and `itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_card).setOnClickListener(this); ` worked. I've removed `itemView.setOnClickListener(this)`. Add it to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code as..

```
public XViewHolder(View itemView, RecyclerView.Adapter adapter) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        this.adapter = adapter;
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.card).setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.download_card).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

and remove the line..

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    **android:clickable="true"** // remove it
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```